# Seaborn lineplot - data based on peaks

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I would like to colour my the lines of a seaborn lineplot, based on where the peak lies. This is my current plot [image: current plot]

As seen, some days the peak is in bin 4.72, whilst in others its 5.24 and 5.83. I would like to colour based on these peaks. So for the plot below, it would have 3 colours, whilst maintaining the dates in the legend.

This is my panda's dataframe, called `select_bins`

```
               2.79  3.1  3.44  3.82  4.25  4.72  5.24  5.83  6.47  7.19  7.99  8.88
date                                                                           
20180527     1   28   101   270   694  1253  1134   528   106    10     0     0
20180603     0    0     0     3    12    26    82    45     5     0     0     0
20180611     2    7    34   137   317   341   410   179    48    10     1     0
20180617     2    6    13    52   130   133   161    74    23     4     0     0
20180625     0    2     1     9    14    34    47    53     9     0     0     0
20180626     5    1     1     5    18    50    72   101    28     2     0     0
20180628     2    0     0     2    21    41    87    78    16     0     0     0
20180705     1    1     0     2    18    32    63    61    27     7     0     0
20180709     2    0     3     6    31    56   107   139    52    12     1     0
```

This is the code to plot. As you can see, I transpose the `select_bins` dataframe to plot

```
ax = sns.lineplot(data = select_bins.T, dashes=False, palette = 'rocket')
plt.show()
```

Comment: If you only have 3 different colors but more lines, how will the legend be useful? You won't be able to distinguish between multiple lines with the same color.

Comment: Is this table correct? Are your columns really called `2.79` and `3.1`? Your image also showed the transposed dataframe. Which one is it?

Comment: @Mr.T yes this is correct. Yes, the headers are numbers, they represent energies. Appreciate the above could be really crude/bad practice. Still learning and would welcome any suggestins.

Comment: @sunnytown I need to see which dates have which peaks, so I thought this was a good way of representing it. I don't anticipate anymore lines (dates). Im still learning, so if you have a better way of doing this, i'd welcome that very much!

Comment: @Mr.T your solution worked, but I see you have taken it down? Anyway, if you want to re-upload it, I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group your data and assign individual color palettes:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

select_bins = pd.read_csv("test.txt", sep="\s{2,}", engine="python", index_col="date")

#identify unique peaks
col_bin = select_bins.idxmax(axis=1)
unique_val = np.unique(col_bin)

#provide information for palettes
palettes = ["Reds", "Blues", "Greys"]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

#plot subgroups with their palettes, providing still individual colors within the palette for each line
for uv, pal in zip (unique_val, palettes):
    sns.lineplot(data = select_bins[col_bin==uv].T, dashes=False, palette = pal, ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]

Alternatively, you could use different line styles for the groups but for this you have to reshape your data first from [wide to long form](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html). And since we have to convert the date to a string anyhow, why not converting the x-values to numbers for a more realistic representation of the curves?

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

select_bins = pd.read_csv("test.txt", sep="\s{2,}", engine="python", index_col="date")
#identify columns to plot
cols=select_bins.columns
#identify peaks
select_bins["col_bin"] = select_bins.idxmax(axis=1)

#reshape data for plotting
plot_df = select_bins.reset_index().melt(id_vars=["date", "col_bin"], value_vars=cols)
plot_df = plot_df.astype({"date": str, "variable": float})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
sns.lineplot(data = plot_df, x="variable", y="value", hue="date", style="col_bin", palette = "rocket", ax=ax)
plt.xticks(ticks=[float(x) for x in cols], labels=cols)

plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Thanks for providing two different approaches. Opted for the latter with the melt() function, because it also helps with another process not posted here. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you create another variables in your dataframe, encoding a value for the peaks `[1,2,3]` for each line and then set this to `hue`:

```
sns.lineplot(data = select_bins.T, dashes=False, palette = 'rocket', hue="peak_encoding")
```

Comment: it throws an error: cant assign hue to wide-form data